# Hardhat how to use revertedWith

Tags: javascript, solidity, chai, assertion, hardhat

I'm writing tests for an ERC-20 contract and I'm testing a scenario that should fail with the (OpenZeppelin library-provided) error:

`revert ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance`

In my terminal output I see:

`ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance`

However when I try the code I can't get test to succeed:

```
 it("Address #1 can't burn 100M tokens", async function () {
    await expect(contract.connect(signer1)
      .burn(parseEther((100_000_000).toString())))
      .revertedWith('revert ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance')
        });
```

I've also tried replacing the string argument to `revertedWith` with "burn amount exceeds balance", "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance", "ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance", and "burn amount exceeds balance" yet all of them are failing.

What exact error reason should I be using with `revertedWith` assertion while testing hardhat with chai? (I'm using standard OpenZeppelin 4 ERC-20 contracts)

Comment: Can you just console.log the type and value of the result of the burn() execution and see what you get back so that you can use an appropriate value for the tests?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis it's super weird as now it worked. Then I realized it was failing if I try ganache network, but now succeeding at local hardhat network. do you know is there any way to make it consistent whether it's hardhat or ganache (without creating custom wrappers that checks for both)?

Comment: Can't really help you on that unfortunately. I would dive into the documentation for the best practices over there: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/other-guides/ganache-tests

Comment: use `--fulltrace` option with hardhat-tracer package to get the exact revert reason. also it may not revert correctly because you are using 'awat' keyword after expect, but await must come before expect because it needs to get the result first, then evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Hardhat is using the same matchers as Waffle. And if you follow the [link](https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matchers.html#revert-with-message), you can see that the proper syntax would be

```
 it("Address #1 can't burn 100M tokens", async function () {
    await expect(contract.connect(signer1)
      .burn(token_amount)
      .to.be.revertedWith('revert ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance')
  });
```